# Show and Hide NSToolbarItems

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

In my application, i need to display toolbars items, 
Initially all the items should be disabled and on a particular action it should be enabled, 
To do so, i am calling following function,

```
-(void)disableToolBarItems{

    NSArray *pToolbarItems=[ptoolbar visibleItems];
    for(int i = 0; i <[pToolbarItems count];i++){
        NSToolbarItem *pItem = [pToolbarItems objectAtIndex:i];
        [pItem setEnabled:NO];
    }

}


-(void)enableToolBarItems{

    NSArray *pToolbarItems=[ptoolbar visibleItems];
    for(int i = 0; i <[pToolbarItems count];i++){
        NSToolbarItem *pItem = [pToolbarItems objectAtIndex:i];
        [pItem setEnabled:YES];
        [pItem validate];
    }
//  [ptoolbar setNeedsDisplay:YES];
    [ptoolbar  validateVisibleItems];
}
```

Both the methods are hitting at proper place and seems to be correct, but toolbar buttons are not getting enabled, 
Should i call some other method to enable and disable it ?

Comment: My first question to you is: do you have your IBOutlet connections set up correctly? (if this applies in your case) Particularly with `ptoolbar`.

Comment: Did you solve this? And when yes, what was the solution?